# What do you call a day that is different from the usual days?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I am looking for a noun or adjective that describes a day that is different from the other usual days, in terms of routine.

My usual routine every day is to stay in the house, do the household chores, feed my dogs, or sometimes go to the mall, stroll, and went back to the house, rest, and the like. My normal days are uneventful and unexciting.

What do you call a day when there's an exciting event happen that made you hyped up and energize?

For example, today I went to the mall and suddenly caught a swindler in the act  of asking money from a student, a part of his modus operandi. I caught him, confronted him, and reported him to the authority. We went to the mall's underground basement and helped the security guards file a complaint to the swindler.

My day was *different and extraordinary* from my usual, boring days.

Comment: Do you want a noun meaning "extraordinary day" or do you want an adjective (similar to 'extraordinary') that describes such a day?  Or as Josh61 has just suggested, do you want an exclamation?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK A noun or adjective can suffice.

Comment: A Special day (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076085/)

Comment: What a day... what a lovely day!

Comment: As opposed to *[Why is this night different from all other nights?](http://www.jewfaq.org/seder.htm)*

Comment: I'm a little chary of these "what's a word for this" questions. English is so big there probably is a word, but it would never be used in ordinary coonversation, and nobody would know what it means. Sometimes it's best to just describe the thing in question rather than seek a precise but arcane word as though it were some qabalistic formula. I mean "what's a word for when I want fish, the wife wants chicken, and the kids want pizza" begins to look like a Question Generator.

Comment: @Feralthinker Says the guy using 'chary'

Comment: "It was a day much different from any other day..."

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Consider the phrase ***[red-letter day](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/red%E2%80%93letter%20day)***.  Merriam Webster says:

> :  of special importance :  memorable "This was a red-letter day in my life."

It sometimes carries a religious connotation, but this is not necessary.  I think Jasmine in the Disney movie "Aladdin" uses it in a song somewhere.

Comment: So called because of the practice of highlighting important days on a calendar with red ink rather than the usual black ink.  See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_letter_day.

Comment: *Red-letter day*: http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/red-letter-day.html

Comment: While helping catch a crook is certainly interesting, I'm not sure it qualifies as a red-letter day. Unless, for example, it inspired the OP to go into law enforcement and truly impacted their life. Otherwise, it was just an unusual event.

Comment: @talmu yes, granted.  I maintain that the word fits with a day that makes you feel "hyped-up and energized" -- the specific kind of day that would qualify as "red-letter" will certainly vary from person to person

Comment: Nice, though I just wonder how many people will understand the intended meaning or will be simply weirded out by this expression...

Comment: @Armfoot I can't imagine anyone being weirded out by this expression.

Comment: @talmu What makes a day a red-letter day for you or for someone else is totally subjective.

Answer (score 9):

You could say:

- Not a run-of-the-mill day

Answer (score 7):

A “remarkable” day. Worthy of remark. Worthy of note. Different than the usual, exceptional.

I suspect Rodale’s Synonym Finder has good alternatives under “remarkable.”

A “standout” day (if you are OK with “standout” as an adjective).

Comment: remarkable is a good word, but it connotation is that of particular positivity, not mere excitement. I like it nonetheless. I would not use standout as an adjective, but I could day something like "Today stood out from the rest"

Comment: @kns98 If [remarkable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/remarkable) has a positive connotation, it's pretty weak. It literally means that the thing is worth remarking on. A lot of awful things are remarkable. Synonyms include rare, strange, and unusual.

Answer (score 5):

If you're not saying anything particularly positive or negative, just that it wasn't a usual day, then how about "an unusual day" ?

Answer (score 1):

How about the phrase "no ordinary", to emphasize that it was indeed extra-ordinary.

Unbeknownst to Mr. soandso, this was no ordinary day. This was the day that would change his life forever ...

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you are looking for is *Exceptional*. [From Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exceptional):

> forming an exception or rare instance; unusual; extraordinary:

For example, "You had an exceptional day."

Answer (score 0):

Passover.

> The Seder tray is moved aside, a second cup of wine is poured, and the child, who by now is bursting with curiosity, asks the time-honored question: “Mah nishtanah ha-lailah hazeh mikol ha-leilot? Why is this night different from all other nights?".... ([The Seder Service in a Nutshell](http://m.chabad.org/holidays/passover/pesach_cdo/aid/1751/jewish/The-Seder-in-a-Nutshell.htm))

Answer (score -1):

**"Today, I wandered into *The Twilight Zone*."** (US)